# build dynamic linq where from checked boxes

Tags: c#, linq

I want to build a dynamic Linq Where clause, with multiple || (ORs), based on user's checked checkboxes

I need my filters to be ||s -- not &&s

Example:

Vehicle:  Car, SUV, Truck

Color:  Black, Blue, Silver, White

Engine:  V4, V6, V8

```
var query = from v in vehicles
            where
                (v.Vehicle == "Car" && v.Color == "Blue")
                || (v.Vehicle == "Truck" && v.Engine == "V8")
                || (v.Vehicle == "Car" && v.Engine == "V4")
            select v;
```

How do I create/append multiple filters with an || operator?

I looked at ScottGu and PredicateBuilder ... but could not figure out how to get it to work

I am still learning Linq

Comment: Do you want to query your DB? What is your current take on chaining the predicates?

Answer (score 1):

Create array of predicates. Each the predicate checks particular condition: blue car, V8 truck or V4 car, etc. Manage content of array and use it like this:

```
delegate bool CheckVehicle(dynamic v); // predicate template

private static bool CheckCarBlue(dynamic v)
{
    return v.Vehicle == "Car" && v.Color == "Blue";
}

private static bool CheckTruckV8(dynamic v)
{
    return v.Vehicle == "Truck" && v.Engine == "V8";
}

private static bool CheckCarV4(dynamic v)
{
    return v.Vehicle == "Car" && v.Engine == "V4";
}
```

somewhere in code:

```
List<CheckVehicle> checks = new List<CheckVehicle>();
checks.Add(CheckCarBlue);
checks.Add(CheckTruckV8);
checks.Add(CheckCarV4);

var Q = from v in vehicles 
        where checks.Any<CheckVehicle>(p => p(v))
        select v;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using functional syntax, this can be done using the following two lines:

```
var CheckedColors = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(c => c.Checked).Select(c => c.Text).ToArray();
var CheckedVehicles = vehicles.Where(v => CheckedColors.Contains(v));
```

The above code assumes that your checkboxes have the same `Text` as the colors you're querying against. The same logic can be extended to query for Engine types as well.

Expalanation: The first line filters all Checkboxes on your form and then creates a projection of the Text property of each checked Checkbox. The second line then filters your vehicles which are present in that list.